Why `ng build` writes information to error log
When I run for example a production build ng build --configuration production, then angular writes some information to the error log:
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
✔ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
✔ Index html generation complete.

The rest of the information is written to the standard log:
Initial chunk files           | Names                                                 |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
main.72ca292f8e263fb1.js      | main                                                  | 932.38 kB |               192.44 kB
styles.27fcf7fbc7060819.css   | styles                                                |  87.92 kB |                 9.32 kB
polyfills.033b0ddba07ded8a.js | polyfills                                             |  33.42 kB |                10.83 kB
runtime.76aa7a1b3ccad887.js   | runtime                                               |   3.02 kB |                 1.45 kB

                              | Initial total                                         |   1.03 MB |               214.05 kB

Lazy chunk files              | Names                                                 |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
604.7a92aba1f690ea24.js       | module-a-module     |  20.59 kB |                 4.94 kB
649.ec93606de2d2b011.js       | module-b-module                         |  18.05 kB |                 4.79 kB
common.fa9b6bffd109eaa4.js    | common                                                |  12.07 kB |                 3.15 kB
295.7fd90ac08182d01c.js       | module-c-module                           |  10.53 kB |                 2.74 kB

Build at: 2024-05-08T08:39:20.285Z - Hash: 8f846dd1da30fa34 - Time: 4153ms
Done in 5.29s.

Why it writes the first lines to error log? Is there a way to adjust this?
Update
Actually it only writes to error log, when it is executed with a maven build:
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
      </plugin>

I think the problem is due to the handling of the log statements in exec-maven-plugin.

I have the same issue.  I also tried using exec-maven-plugin versions 3.0.0 and 3.4.1 which is the latest, but the same issue prevailed.  I have it in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79062713/exec-maven-plugin-interprets-npm-and-ng-warnings-as-errors?noredirect=1#comment139407500_79062713.  ...

... Did you find solution?  I tried pretty much anything and only configuring my Angular package.json scripts where ng build is called to be like ng build --configuration production 2>&1 worked.  But I dont like that solution since it will redirect all STDERR messages to STDOUT meaning bot true and fake errors will be reported as INFO messages.

Two options you can try in ng build
--progress

Log progress to the console while building.
Type: boolean
Default: true

--verbose

Adds more details to output logging.
Type: boolean
Default: false


@LorenzPfisterer usually the logs contains the entire stack trace because it better to debug knowing the entire flow! we can just grep the [error] lines easily, in this log!
